# C++ Dynamically load classes

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, dll, load

Im still a bit new to C++, so bear with my noobiness.

What I want is to be able to allow the user of my program to be able to add his own classes. I have an abstract class `Module`, and my application consists of a set of subclasses of `Module`.

Is it possible to be able to search a particular directory and dynamically load subclasses of `Module` (added by the user) ?

In Java I could achieve this using the org.reflections API.
I'm guessing the C++ equivalent is using DLLs. I may be wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible using dynamic linking shread library. It would be platform spercific, of cause. You may consider using `Qt` ([Qt plugins](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/plugins-howto.html)) or some other plugin system.

Answer (score 7):

To my knowledge the C++ compilation model doesn't have an explicit, direct way of "exporting classes". However, you should be able to do it with a simple C-interface:

```
#include "MyModule.h"

// class MyModule inherits Module

extern "C" Module * create_module() { return new MyModule; }
extern "C" void free_module(Module * p) { delete p; }
```

Now you can dynamically load that library and retrieve the functions `create_module` and `free_module`, and add their function pointers dynamically to your system:

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<Module * (*)(), void(*)(Module *)> plugins;

plugins["MyClass"] = std::make_pair(..., ...);   // the dynamically resolved
                                                 // function addresses
```

In fact, you probably don't even need the destroyer function, since the ordinary virtual destructor machinery should work even in dynamically loaded libraries.

For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<Module> make_module(std::string const & s)
{
    auto it = plugins.find(s);

    return { it == plugins.end() ? nullptr : it->second.first() };
}
```

Comment: There are a number of do's and dont's when doing dynamically loading c++ classes in this way when needing to maintain ABI stability. See 
https://community.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B

Comment: Nice solution. You can find the same way [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3687) as in the context Kerrek provides.